# How to properly request facebook permissions ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a bunch of facebook information from user using the app using parse and the facebook sdk, but I haven't been able to do it successfully.

First I check if the user is logged in and if they arn't I display the parse view controller with facebook permissions.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if (![PFUser currentUser] || ![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {

    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"public_profile", @"user_birthday", @"user_photos", @"user_about_me", @"user_likes", @"user_relationship_details"];

    LoginViewController *logInViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [logInViewController setDelegate:self];

    [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:permissionsArray, nil]];

    [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];

    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

} else {
        [self getUserInfo];
    }
}
```

Then, once the user is logged in, I attempt to get the following permissions like so.

```
-(void)getUserInfo {

FBSDKGraphRequest *requestMe = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
FBSDKGraphRequest *requestBirthday = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me/user_birthday" parameters:nil];
FBSDKGraphRequest *requestPhotos = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:nil];
FBSDKGraphRequest *requestAboutMe = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me/about_me" parameters:nil];
FBSDKGraphRequest *requestLikes = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                   initWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes"
                                   parameters:nil
                                   HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
FBSDKGraphRequest *requestRelationship = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me/relationship_details" parameters:nil];


FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

[connection addRequest:requestMe completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    userName = result[@"name"];
    userGender = result[@"gender"];
    userId = result[@"id"];

    if (connection) {
        [self setMe];
    }

}];

[connection addRequest:requestBirthday completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

}];

[connection addRequest:requestPhotos completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

}];

[connection addRequest:requestAboutMe completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

}];

[connection addRequest:requestLikes completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

}];

[connection addRequest:requestRelationship completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

}];


    [connection start];

}
```

The `requestMe` works perfectly and I retrieve the users information, however when I get the NSLog to output the result of any of the other permissions, its always `null` and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. In the documentation it says that the app doesn't have to go through review if the developer wants to retrieve information about himself, so the problem isn't that the app hasn't been reviewed.

Why can't I retrieve the information? Is it because I am requesting the information wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think there is not a problem on ur code side. Please make sure your facebook account is associated with the FacebookID. Did you add a tester user on the facebook setting? you can use access_token to run the facebookGraph.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I can log into my app and retrieve some basic info but I am looking to fix the other permissions I ask for that should be available.

Comment: Did you get the response log from the server? Do you get access_granted for particular permission u r asking for?

Comment: It always returns saying I don't have the permission, however I don't think that part applies seeing as I am the developer of the app and I don't need to submit my app for review? Thats only if I want other people to be able to use my app?

Comment: you can use public_access_token to get that permission for certain period. But if you want to get the data when you request the user, you need to submit the app to get approval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot request extended permissions if your app didn't went through Login Review yet. The only exception is if you're using a admin/tester/developer user while testing your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0